# In java: is there a way to round a double number without using methods?

Tags: java, double, rounding

I have a very simple code and I am not used to deal with libraries, yet. I want a way to round the number like what we do in "C" (%.2).

Comment: Do you mean there is no simple way?

Comment: Do the standard libraries, the JDK, count as _libraries_?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand the question correctly,

```
double x = 1.2764;
double x_to_2_decimals = (int)(x * 100 + 0.5) / 100.0;
```

Answer (score 2):

It depends on exactly what you want to do. If you are seeking the equivalent of C's

```
printf("%.2f", doubleValue);
```

you can use:

```
System.out.println( String.format("%.2f", doubleValue) );
```

This uses standard Java code that would be available in all JVMs, ie. no external libraries are required.

Comment: That's JUST what I need. Thanks

Comment: You could also just write `System.out.printf("%.2f%n", doubleValue)`.

Comment: @IbrahimAlawwad Happy to help. You can of course accept my answer (hint, hint) :)